# How to show error on missing parameters for options?

Tags: clojure, clojure-contrib

I'm an absolute Clojure beginner and I'm trying to build a CLI app using the clojure.tools.cli library.

My problem is that I can't show any error when an option is not provided with required parameter.

What I want:

```
$ java -jar test.jar -m SAMPLE
Given file: SAMPLE

$ java -jar test.jar -m
ERROR: Please provide a file
```

What happens:

```
$ java -jar test.jar -m SAMPLE
Given file: SAMPLE

$ java -jar test.jar -m

$
```

It doesn't show anything.

Here is my code:

```
(ns obmed-clj.core
  (:require [clojure.tools.cli :refer [parse-opts]])
  (:gen-class))

(def cli-options
  [["-m" "--menu FILE" "Provide menu file path"
    :parse-fn #(if (nil? %) 
                   (println "ERROR: Please provide a file") 
                   %)
    :validate-fn #(println "Given file:" %)]])

(defn -main [& args]
  (parse-opts args cli-options))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are abusing the `-fn` arguments here a little.  Their use is to convert the "string" (in your case, since you have `"--menu FILE"`) and then do additional validation on that (but rather use `:validate [fn msg]` instead).  So e.g.:

```
user=> (def cli-opts [["-m" "--menu FILE" "menu file" 
            :parse-fn #(java.io.File. %) 
            :validate [#(.exists %) "file must exist"]]])
#'user/cli-opts
```

Missing argument:

```
user=> (parse-opts ["-m"] cli-opts)
{:arguments [],
 :errors ["Missing required argument for \"-m FILE\""],
 :options {},
 :summary "  -m, --menu FILE  menu file"}
```

File not existing:

```
user=> (parse-opts ["-m" "XXX"] cli-opts)
{:arguments [],
 :errors ["Failed to validate \"-m XXX\": file must exist"],
 :options {},
 :summary "  -m, --menu FILE  menu file"}
```

All is well:

```
user=> (parse-opts ["-m" "/etc/hosts"] cli-opts)
{:arguments [],
 :errors nil,
 :options {:menu #<java.io.File@34d63c80 /etc/hosts>},
 :summary "  -m, --menu FILE  menu file"}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I've added `(println (get parsed :errors))` to show errors if found. I realized that tools.cli is more complete than I thought.